# Upgrade from 17.10 -> 18.04 crashing on qdbus-qt5 install

Tags: upgrade, dpkg

I am unable to upgrade 17.10 to 18.04 because the installation of `qdbus-qt5` is failing. This is actually kubuntu, but I have asked the question on the kubuntu and ubuntu forums, as well as launchpad, and have not been able to resolve the problem. The upgrade goes fine until it reaches `qdbus-qt5`, at which point it crashes and cannot go any further. I tried purging `qbdus-qt5` (and most of kde along with it), and the upgrade goes through, but still cannot install `qbdus-qt5` and therefore kde.

Trying to manually install `qdbus-qt5` with `dpkg`, I get the following error:

```
root@Crynfyd:/# dpkg -i /var/cache/apt/archives/qdbus-qt5_5.9.5-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
(Reading database ... 839516 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../qdbus-qt5_5.9.5-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking qdbus-qt5 (5.9.5-0ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/qdbus-qt5_5.9.5-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--install):
unable to open '/usr/lib/qt5/bin/qdbus.dpkg-new': No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/qdbus-qt5_5.9.5-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

Basically it is supposed to be creating the file */usr/lib/qt5/bin/qdbus.dpkg-new* , but it is deleting it instead. If I touch the file, it deletes it and quits. Some sort of strange conundrum that I can't get around.

More details in launchpad here:

https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/qttools-opensource-src/+question/668259

Any help or ideas much appreciated. Please, no "fresh install", that is impractical and not a solution. I don't really know where the problem is, whether a problem with `qdbus-qt5`, `dpkg`, or whatever else I cannot imagine as others don't seem to be having this problem, and it isn't occurring with other packages (well, it does occur with other `qtcreator` packages, but I have purged those before the upgrade). This is a real mess and it is blocking the whole upgrade process.

---

### Updates

**Problem Solved.**

The symptom:

Ugrade from 17.10 -> 18.04 crashes while trying to install qdbus-qt5.
Trying to manually install the package produces this error:

---

```
root@Crynfyd:/# dpkg -i /var/cache/apt/archives/qdbus-   qt5_5.9.5-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
(Reading database ... 839516 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../qdbus-qt5_5.9.5-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking qdbus-qt5 (5.9.5-0ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/qdbus-qt5_5.9.5-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--install):
unable to open '/usr/lib/qt5/bin/qdbus.dpkg-new': No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/qdbus-qt5_5.9.5-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

---

Here is the problem:

In artful, the package qdbus-qt5 installs its binary to
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/qdbus .  The directory /usr/lib/qt5 is
actually a symbolic link to /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5 .  So 
ls /usr/lib/qt5/bin/ produces a list of files that looks real, but they aren't
really there. I noticed that doing a dpkg-query --search /usr/lib/qt5/bin/qdbus
produced no results, and wondered why, as the files looked like they were there.

In bionic, the package qdbus-qt5 installs its binary to /usr/lib/qt5/bin/qdbus,
and installs a symlink in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/qdbus that points to
/usr/lib/qt5/bin/qdbus .

So when trying to upgrade from artful to bionic, the package installs its binary
into a directory that is a symlink to /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/ and
then tries to install the symlink to the file the directory actually points to.
I discovered this while trying to manually install the files from the package,
and files were just disappearing. This is what dpkg has been screaming about all
along.

There is a problem, therefore, in the upgrade process going from which files are
symlinks and which are actual binaries. The upgrade process evidently doesn't
address this problem. I read somewhere that the upgrade from 16.04 -> 18.04
won't be in place until July; this may be one of the reasons why, and maybe the
same problem going from 17.10 -> 18.04. There may be other problems that have
not surfaced as of yet.

Note that this same problem also exists for several other packages, mostly
connected with QT Creator:

```
qtcreator 
qtcreator-data
qtcreator-doc
qmlscene
qt5-qmake
qttools5-dev-tools
qtbase5-dev-tools
```

And maybe others I haven't found yet.
They can be removed prior to the upgrade, though in my test they did
not cause any problems after applying the hack below.

SHAMELESS HACK to fix this for the upgrade:

```
## Remove the symlink:
sudo rm /usr/lib/qt5
## Do a hard copy of the relevant files:
sudo cp -r /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5 /usr/lib/
```

I also noticed there is some sort of problem with locales; fix for that:

```
export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
sudo locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

Then upgrade/dist-upgrade (or do-release-upgrade, or however you do it). 
Still needed the occasional apt-get install -f / dpkg --configure -a / 
dpkg -i --force-overwrite , but seems to go through as expected.

So much for "fresh install".

PS: Thanks to those who offered help. The bit about dpkg -x ing the package, and the bizarre results it produced, is what tipped me on this.

Comment: This appears to be a problem unique to your setup. Do you know what caused your computer to be set up that way? Is this a system that has been upgraded multiple times across many versions of Ubuntu?

Comment: Right, this system has been upgraded multiple times since Xenial (16.04). This is the first time there has been any problem like this. Since from the release notes they intend to provide an upgrade path from Xenial to Bionic, I suspect this is a problem that will eventually be addressed.

Answer (score 2):

Before attempting to upgrade, you should ensure that no PPAs or non-standard repositories are installed.  This can be done from a GUI, such as `synaptic`, but I usually look directly in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`.

After removing PPAs and non-standard repositories, update and safe-upgrade.  I prefer to use `aptitude` because it automatically resolves conflicts, which requires extra switches in `apt`/`apt-get`/`dpkg`:

```
sudo aptitude update
sudo aptitude safe-upgrade
```

Then dist-upgrade:

```
sudo aptitude dist-upgrade
```

If you have problems with dist-upgrade, there are probably conflicts caused obsolete packages, which were in 17.10, but removed from 18.04.  You can try one or more of the following:

1. Install only manually installed packages:

   ```
   sudo aptitude install `apt-mark showmanual`
   ```

   Remove packages `aptitude` complains about with `sudo aptitude remove [package]` and reattempt.
2. Find and install upgradable packages:

   ```
   aptitude search '~U' -F '%p'
   ```

   You can try to upgrade them all at once with:

   ```
   sudo aptitude remove `aptitude -s search '~U' -F '%p'`
   ```
3. Find and remove obsolete packages.  To get a list of packages that are obsolete, you can use:

   ```
   aptitude search '~o' -F '%p'
   ```

   To remove them all at once, you can try the following command, but if it wants to remove more than a *few dozen packages*, you should skip it:

   ```
   sudo aptitude remove `aptitude -s search '~o' -F '%p'`
   ```

Then try again to install kubuntu-desktop or kubuntu-full or whatever packages you want:

```
sudo aptitude install kubuntu-desktop
```

In case you are still having problems, the `deb` file may be corrupt.  Choose one of the following:

1. `sudo \rm /var/cache/apt/cache/*qdbus*`
   You can use similar commands to remove the debs of any packages that appear to be causing problems.
2. `sudo aptitude clean` – This will remove all cached deb files.

Comment: It is great, but OP has some special problems with '/usr/lib/qt5/bin/qdbus.dpkg-new' file. Your solution is about manual TUI upgrade, not about this problem.

Comment: OP wants kde installed. Beyond that, I doubt OP cares about particular files. `dpkg` tends to throw all sorts of misleading errors when there are conflicting packages. That is what should be dealt with first.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your suggestions. I have to say that I do not trust aptitude -- it has destroyed my system once before I knew better, and threatened to do so more than once, so no.  But the idea of removing all of the packages to be removed in a separate operation prior to doing the upgrade is one I haven't tried, and will give that a shot. FSCK done, no problems. I have manually downloaded the deb file and tried installing it, same results. I always do the upgrade with sources.list.d disabled; I have tried both ways, same result. I also did try apt-get update/upgrade/dist-upgrade, no joy.

Comment: FYI - for the fun of it, I ran the aptitude search '~o' -F '%p' command; it wants to remove 866 packages, while apt-get dist-upgrade wants to remove 87, so I don't think I will hit that button.

Comment: Further comments addeed as an "answer". Sorry, I don't know much about editing comments here.

Answer (score 0):

At first check your file-system with `fsck` during boot (<kbd>Shift</kbd> in GRUB, select *Advanced options*, select *.... (recovery mode)*, in *Recovery menu* select *fsck - Check all filesystems*) or from Ubuntu 18.04 LiveCD/USB.

Then ensure that you do not have broken packages:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Remove downloaded deb-package as it may be corrupted:

```
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/qdbus-qt5_5.9.5-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

You can try to download this package again with

```
cd /var/cache/apt/archives/
sudo wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/q/qttools-opensource-src/qdbus-qt5_5.9.5-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

for sure you can create the folder for *qdbus.dpkg-new*:

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/lib/qt5/bin/
```

and install it forcing all problems

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-all qdbus-qt5_5.9.5-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install -f
```

or install it with `apt-get`:

```
sudo apt-get install ./qdbus-qt5_5.9.5-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

Other hacky way is to extract deb-package directly with

```
sudo dpkg -x qdbus-qt5_5.9.5-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb /
```

and then ask `apt-get` to reinstall it

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall qdbus-qt5
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried those things. If I create the file, then install with dpkg -i --force-all, it comes back with the same error, and after that, the file I created is gone.

Comment: I can of course extract the package and manually install the files, and that works, but apt knows nothing about it and therefore will not install the kde packages (most of kde) that depend on it. I have been the install -f, dpkg --configure -a, apt-get --fix-broken round and round, but it always quits in the same place -- with the above quoted error.

Comment: See top part about `fsck`. Are you sure that filesystem is consistent? Are you sure that disk does not have read errors and bad-blocks? I can't find any normal reason for problems with writing *qdbus.dpkg-new* file.

Comment: For `fsck`, easier to use `sudo touch /forcefsck` then reboot.